# Litmus test for discerning worthy counterparty of medieval trade

Tags: economy, medieval, trade

Medieval Europe tends to be regarded as an example of significant fragmented sovereignty. That is to say multiple entities would stake claim to the same land and/or inhabitants. Of course there were the state powers, but there were also a constellation of other institutions ranging from the pope, monastic orders, vassals and chivalric orders. [Sean McFate](https://www.atlanticcouncil.org/expert/sean-mcfate/) writes:

> The great Khan also maintained an embassy at Avignon, where Pope
> Benedict XII held his court, and in this way, both political
> authorities kept diplomatic relations, even though the Church was not
> a state.

I'm trying to craft a reliable framework for an foreign (Asian) trade guild to discern which group to choose. An easy solution would be to not discriminate and establish trade links with any and all. But for the purposes of my world, I would like to stipulate that only one counterparty is allowed.

### Question

As a total outlander trade guild arriving in Medieval Europe, how might one recognize the best counterparty and what kind of litmus test would be in order to build conviction?

Comment: This seems like less a fact of your world and more a challenge that a character in your world needs to resolve for theirself, given their specific circumstances.

Comment: @sphennings I don't dispute there is an element of my 'world-specific' nature to the question, but the heart of the question is about how to integrate my world with the existing/historical Medieval institutions, which, IMO, is fair game. But I have been wrong plenty in the past ha

Comment: @ArashHowaida As written you're asking about the actions of characters. If you want to revise your question to ask something less character driven, and instead ask about "how were trade relations established in medieval Europe?" that should be a pretty easy [edit] to make.

Comment: Merchant/trade guild view: Which party offers the better deal? Be that concessions, less likely to seize goods, actual price of goods, other goods for the back haul etc.

Comment: @ArashHowaida It's a lot dependent on what your goals and resources are, and I can't seem to find them. Do you have specific goals to reach? There're more to gain than wealth, and you have one good deal for each kind and amount of goods you're willing to part from That's what I believe Sphennings saw in your question.

Comment: If you want to establish trade relationships between distant partners, there might be a problem with that. In medieval world, trade was done in a chain of short links, and one particular bag of spice was changing many hands on its way between, say, China and France. Vendor who wants to be able to pick partners needs a way to control the whole trade route to this partner.

Comment: Can you clarify "significant fragmented sovereignty… multiple entities would stake claim to the same land and/or inhabitants…"?

Don't you think vassals were both part of and subject to states, and chivalric orders to the papacy?

How could "the Great Khan also maintained an embassy at Avignon, where Pope Benedict XII held his court, and in this way, both political authorities kept diplomatic relations, even though the Church was not a state" help understanding?

Answer (score 1):

### Textiles, Flanders

In medieval times, there existed trade over the Silk route. It involved silk, pottery, spices.. Now suppose people from the East would want to get a stronghold in trade. They could consider concentrating their silk trade on Flanders, which used to produce and paint cloth from English wool. More silk from the east could have meant silk pajamas's and underwear affordable for Europeans in the 14th century.. an inflow of Chinese artists to do the painting into Europe, and Chinese silk farms to flourish from their enlarged silk export yields. Win win.

This scenario could have had an interesting followup: as silk clothes and wool clothes exist for different purposes, the wool guilds would not have to regard the Eastern tradesmen as competition, and they could learn new techniques. [The textiles guilds in Flanders](https://wiki.p2pfoundation.net/Medieval_Textile_Worker%27s_Craft_Guilds_in_the_Low_Countries), weaving and painting the wool, would profit from more volume in textiles, requiring innovation in production. The [Industrious revolution](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-economic-history/article/abs/industrial-revolution-and-the-industrious-revolution/CF3AE82F17442FEE4C3045507A5FF606) in Europe may have set in 200 years earlier.